# Number of elements in each nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a nested list as:
[[A,B,A,A],[C,C,B,B],[A,C,B,B]]..... so on

I need to print number of A's, B's and C's in each nested list. And also print total number of elements in each nested list:

```
For first nested list:
A = 3
B = 1
#Should not print C!
total = 4

For second nested list:
C = 2
B = 2
#Should not print A!
total = 4

...
...
...
so on
```

Can anyone please tell me how to code this in python?

Comment: I would suggest you to attempt solving the problem first and give us what you already got. It will be easier to take it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> bigList = [['A','B','A','A'],['C','C','B','B'],['A','C','B','B']]
>>> for index,subList in enumerate(bigList):
...    print(index)
...    print(Counter(subList))
...    print('---')
...
0
Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 1})
---
1
Counter({'C': 2, 'B': 2})
---
2
Counter({'B': 2, 'A': 1, 'C': 1})
---
```

Comment: Using `Counter` is awesome solution!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple, easy to understand way to do it would be to just check for A, B, and C and add 1 to a counter.

```
nested_list = [['A','B','A','A'],['C','C','B','B'],['A','C','B','B']]

number_of_a = 0
number_of_b = 0
number_of_c = 0


for lists in nested_list:
    for item in lists:
        if item == 'A':
             number_of_a += 1
        elif item == 'B':
             number_of_b += 1
        elif item == 'C':
             number_of_c += 1

print number_of_a, number_of_b, number_of_c
```

Happy coding, and best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using collections.Counter seems to be a cleanest way.
However, you can try this, the idea is to use a dictionary to keep track of number of times each element appears. (untested code though).

```
for list in nested_list:
    dict = {}
    for element in list:
        if not dict[element]:
            dict[element] = 1
        else:
            dict[element] += 1
    print(dict)
    print(count(dict))
```